# Can I install Windows 7 64-bit as a guest OS in a VM onto a Windows 7 32-bit?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

I want to install Windows 7 **64-bit** for my physical machine, and then install Windows 7 **32-bit** as a guess OS in a virtual machine, can this be done? If yes, what virtual machine software to use? My CPU is i5 760.

Comment: Uhhh, your question title and actual question do not match up, the title is basically "64-bit *guest* on 32-bit *host* " while your question itself is "64-bit *host* with 32-bit *guest* "  while with Virtualbox both ways are possible (I have done both) your question is left ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! And good to know that both are possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that.

The tree top virtual machine software are:

- [Oracle VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (free)
- [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/) (not free)
- [MS Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) (free)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done.  I have done it myself with Oracle's VirtualBox, using a 32-bit version of Windows XP as the host and a 64-bit version of Windows 7 as the guest.  It works pretty well.